# Facebook Graph Post link problems

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a link to the wall of a facebook Page through the graph api. 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Unfortunately the api is not very well documentet so i have some problems:

- How do i get the "Share"-action to appear under a link i've posted?
- How can i disable thumbnails for the link?
- How can i make the caption linked

All those works when posting manually but i havn't found a way to do it through the api. I know it's possible though since i've seen other apps do it.